# Не получается отловить исключение при валидации Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

Отправляю `json` методом `post` на контроллер через curl.
В контроллере написано следующее:

```
try
{
    $input = $this->request->getJSON(true);
    $this->validation->setRules([
        'arrayValues.*.someId'  => 'trim|required|string'
    ]);
    $this->validation->run($input);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $result = false;
}
```

Ожидаемый верный декодированный массив:

```
$decodedArray = ['arrayValues' => [['someId' => 'qwe'],['someId' => 'ewq']]];
```

В результате выполнения получаю ошибку внутри блока `try/catch` и в блок `catch` не переходит.

Это происходит если приходят данные, не во вложенном массиве: `"Argument 2 passed to _array_search_dot() must be of the type array, string given, called in /codeigniter/system/Helpers/array_helper.php on line 56`:

```
$decodedArray = ['arrayValues' => ['someId' => 'qwe']];
```

Если приходит пустой массив, то получаю ошибку `/codeigniter/system/Validation/Validation.php(266): trim()` -> `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`, но она ловится в `try/catch` нормально.

```
$decodedArray = ['arrayValues' => []];
```

Почему такое происходит и как от этого избавиться?

Comment: Потому что это не Ошибка, а по сути предупреждение при чём самого PHP, а не движка. Можно попробовать написать `catch (\Throwable`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это сработало. Благодарю! Но я удивлён, что CI не проверяет данную ситуацию

Comment: @Pashok возможно, CI в этом случае выкидывает своё кастомное исключение, которое не наследуется от Exception, соответственно, и блок catch игнорируется. Throwable - это общий интерфейс всех исключений, который сработает на любое из них